# black screen on startup on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I install  Ubuntu 14.04 fresh on my system and whenever I switch  on my system in first attempt it open as black screen. So I directly switched off the system and again try to switch on and only with many attempt I could find `grub` menu.

How do I fix this problem please help me. I do not have any graphics card such as nvidia.

Comment: Does the machine boot up OK into ubuntu using the install CD ?   That is, running ubuntu from the CD not from the installed ubuntu.

Comment: Yes machine boot okay whenever I use LIVE usb  to BOOT even i reinstall still that problem

Comment: Go through instructions at https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it    This is fixable , I have had this issue before on a different laptop

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried re-installing Ubuntu? Perhaps there was a hiccup in the installation.

There can be many reasons this can happen; Is this being installed on a brand new hard drive, is is the only OS on the drive? What media did you use to install Ubuntu?

Comment: yes it is only os in my drive.

Comment: i reinstalled 2 or 3 times stilllproblem remain

Comment: i use LIVE USB to install